# jquery prevent form transmission not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am wondering why my piece of code is not working as i expect..

```
$( "#FormWithAddress" ).submit(function(e) {
        // Check if componentForm is filled if not, get addressAutocomplete input and use geocode
        // if return false; or e.preventDefault; is here, the form can't be submitted
        if( $('#geo_longitude').val().length === 0 || $('#geo_latitude').val().length === 0) {
            var searchValue = $("#addressAutocomplete").val();

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': searchValue}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    //results[0].geometry.location
                    fillInputForm(results[0], results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                } else {
                    if ($("#addressAutocomplete").parent().find( ".error-message" ).length == 0) {
                        $("#addressAutocomplete").parent().append("<div class='error-message'>Error message here...</div>");
                    }
                    alert('reached');
                    // if return false; or e.preventDefault; is here, form always get submitted but alert is shown.

                }
            });
        }

    });
```

See the comments: if `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();` is in the first line, all works fine the form is not submitted. If the `return false` or `e.preventDefault` is in else case, the alert is shown and the form is submitted. What i am doing wrong? Many thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geocode` method is asynchronous, it's too late to prevent the form from submitting by the time the `geocode` fires the callback.

You have to always prevent the submit, and then just submit the form in the asynchronous callback

```
$("#FormWithAddress").submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('#geo_longitude').val().length === 0 || $('#geo_latitude').val().length === 0) {
        var searchValue = $("#addressAutocomplete").val(),
            form = this;

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': searchValue
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                //results[0].geometry.location
                fillInputForm(results[0], results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());

                form.submit();

            } else {

                if ($("#addressAutocomplete").parent().find(".error-message").length == 0) {
                    $("#addressAutocomplete").parent().append("<div class='error-message'>Error message here...</div>");
                }

                alert('reached');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

geocoder.geocode takes a second argument which is a function.  This function has its own scope so when you return you are not returning from your form submission, you are returning from the geocoder.

you could cancel the form submit always as you have commented out then if you want to submit the for submit it from inside the geocoder callback function?